# Bash Script to read specific part of text file and email results

Tags: bash, shell

So I have batch files that run everyday and they take the command line output and put it into a text file that gets over-ridden on the desktop. I want to use a script to ONLY get the results at the very end of the output which looks something like;

```
================================================================
Test abcd | passed: 12 | failed: 15 | skipped 42 
=================================================================
```

I want to:

> 1. Read in the output at the very bottom of the text file which is formatted as shown above
> 2. Read from MULTIPLE text files into 1 single email (there will be approximately 5 different outputs all in the same format with different results and different test names)
> 3. Email it in a table format as follows in the email
>
>    ```
>               Pass | Fail  | Skipped 
>
>     Test 1 |   10  |  15   |   20
>
>     Test 2 |   10  |  15   |   20
>    ```
>
> 4.The email needs to be sent every day after the actual tests run ( I have already automated the tests)

Comment: Are those `=========` lines also included in your output? And how many instances of `Test ... | passed: ... | failed: ... | skipped ...` in one output do you get?

Comment: Yes those ===== lines are included in the output. There is only 1 instance of results per text file.

Comment: @user3791161 According to your previous comment, I've edited the formatting of your question. Please check if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -C1 'Test.*passed:.*failed:.*skipped' filename | mail -s "The Subject" recipient@example.com
```

Comment: Does this just grap the results with no formatting? I want it to come out in a table. Also I have mutiple text files for outputs, can I use this to take multiple outputs?

Comment: Added the `-C1` option, which also extract 1 line above and 1 line below the match. That should include the "===" lines

Comment: When you say "multiple outputs", do you want multiple emails or all the results in a single email? You need to provide more details in your question.

Comment: Multiple outputs to one email.

Comment: You have to update your question to specify all your requirements. Then ask me again.

Comment: Should be better now.

Comment: Can you adapt what I've shown? Where are you having trouble?